# :target is not showing

Tags: html, css, target

I am building an on-boarding screen.

It has few cards, you can switch between them using the next and back buttons.

[image: cards]

I've been trying to make the next and back buttons work using only :target

So, I've given each card an ID and each button a href="#id".

As far as I can tell, everything is set up for it to work, but it is not working.

```css
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
/*onboarding canvas*/
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
#onboarding-canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10000000;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

  /*==========================================================================*/
  /*onboarding intro*/
  #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-intro {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4E42C3;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    pointer-events: none;
    animation-name: onboardingIntro;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 13s;
  }
  @keyframes onboardingIntro {
    0% {
    }
    100% {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes onboardingIntro {
    0% {
    }
    100% {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
  }

    #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-intro-stages {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

      #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-intro-stage {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -40px;
        left: 0; right: 0;
        opacity: 0;
      }

        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-intro-stage p {
          font-size: 1.7em;
        }


    /*onboarding intro animation*/
    #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-intro .stage1 {
      animation-name: onboardingIntroStage1;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-delay: 1s;
    }
    #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-intro .icon-hand-wave {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 2em;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    @keyframes onboardingIntroStage1 {
      0% {
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes onboardingIntroStage1 {
      0% {
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-intro .stage2 {
      animation-name: onboardingIntroStage2;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-delay: 5s;
    }
    @keyframes onboardingIntroStage2 {
      0% {
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes onboardingIntroStage2 {
      0% {
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-intro .stage3 {
      animation-name: onboardingIntroStage2;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-delay: 9s;
    }
    @keyframes onboardingIntroStage3 {
      0% {
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes onboardingIntroStage3 {
      0% {
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }

    /*onboarding fireworks*/
    #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-intro .fireworks {
      pointer-events: none;
      animation-name: onboarding-intro-fireworks;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-delay: 5s;
    }
    @keyframes onboarding-intro-fireworks {
      0% {
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes onboarding-intro-fireworks {
      0% {
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }


  /*==========================================================================*/
  /*onboarding card*/
  #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-cards {
    background-color: rgba(39,47,65,0.95);
    padding: 20px 20px 90px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: table;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
  }

    /*onboarding card wrapper*/
    #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-wrapper {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: none;
    }
    #onboarding-canvas > div > div:target {
      display: table-cell;
    }

  #onboarding-canvas > div > div:first-of-type {
    display: table-cell;
  }

    /*onboarding card content*/
    #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;

      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(39,47,65,0.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(39,47,65,0.2);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(39,47,65,0.2);
    }


      /*card image*/
      #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-image {

      }

        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-image img {
          border-top-left-radius: 4px;
          border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        }


      /*card content*/
      #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-content {
        padding: 30px;
      }

        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-content .card-title {
          font-size: 1.16em;
          position: relative;
          top: -5px;
          margin-bottom: -7px;
        }

          #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-content .card-title span {
            color: #4E42C3;
            font-weight: bold;
          }


      /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
      /*card tips*/
      #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-tips {
        border-top: 1px solid #E6ECF0;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 30px;
      }

        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-tips .label {
          color: #48556B;
          background-color: #fff;
          border: 1px solid #E6ECF0;
          margin-right: 6px;
        }

        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-tips {

        }


      /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
      /*card features*/
      #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-features {

      }

        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-features li {
          margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-features li:last-of-type {
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-features li i {
          color: #4E42C3;
          font-size: 1.2em;
        }


      /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
      /*card action buttons*/
      #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-actions {
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-actions .button {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: transparent;
          border: 2px solid #fff;
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 0 7px;
        }
        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-actions .button:hover {
          background-color: #fff;
          color: #272F41;
        }
        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-actions .next-button {
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card-actions .back-button {
          border: 2px solid transparent;
        }


    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #onboarding-canvas .onboarding-card.card1 {

    }
```

```html
<div id="onboarding-canvas">

  <div class="onboarding-cards">

   <div class="onboarding-card-wrapper" id="onboardingCard1">
    <div class="onboarding-card card1">
     <div class="onboarding-card-image">
      <img src="https://plutio.com/app/onboarding/onboarding-card-1.gif" />
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-content">
      <p class="card-title"><span>Create tasks</span> for whatever needs to get done. Plutio will help keep your tasks list organized so you can stay focused.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-tips">
      <p><span class="label">Good to know</span> Your tasks are automatically sorted into categories, there is a category for what's due today, tomorrow and next week.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-actions">
      <a class="button next-button next">Nice, what's next?</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="onboarding-card-wrapper" id="onboardingCard2">
    <div class="onboarding-card card2">
     <div class="onboarding-card-image">
      <img src="https://plutio.com/app/onboarding/onboarding-card-2.gif" />
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-content">
      <p class="card-title"><span>Manage your projects</span> in one place. Create and sort their tasks in milestones or progress stages, upload files and replace messy emails with focused discussions.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-tips">
      <p><span class="label">Good to know</span> You can customize the set of statuses every project moves through during their lifecycle.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-actions">
      <a class="button back-button back" href="#onboardingCard1">Back</a>
      <a class="button next-button next" href="#onboardingCard3">Next</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="onboarding-card-wrapper" id="onboardingCard3">
    <div class="onboarding-card card3">
     <div class="onboarding-card-image">
      <img src="https://plutio.com/app/onboarding/onboarding-card-3.gif" />
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-content">
      <p class="card-title"><span>Collaborate with your clients and contributors</span>. Start private conversations or create group channels and get everyone involved.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-tips">
      <p><span class="label">Good to know</span> When you create a project, a dedicated channel with all the project contributors is automatically created.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-actions">
      <a class="button back-button back" href="#onboardingCard2">Back</a>
      <a class="button next-button next" href="#onboardingCard4">Next</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="onboarding-card-wrapper" id="onboardingCard4">
    <div class="onboarding-card card4">
     <div class="onboarding-card-image">
      <img src="https://plutio.com/app/onboarding/onboarding-card-4.gif" />
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-content">
      <p class="card-title"><span>Manage your business contacts</span>. No more sifting through emails and business cards. Plutio brings your clients, contributors and contacts to one place.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-tips">
      <p><span class="label">Good to know</span> Your clients can only view projects and tasks that are assigned to them.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-actions">
      <a class="button back-button back" href="#onboardingCard3">Back</a>
      <a class="button next-button next" href="#onboardingCard5">Next</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="onboarding-card-wrapper" id="onboardingCard5">
    <div class="onboarding-card card4">
     <div class="onboarding-card-image">
      <img src="https://plutio.com/app/onboarding/onboarding-card-5.gif" />
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-content">
      <p class="card-title"><span>{{ customer.first_name }}, say hi to Leo, your very own account manager!</span> Feel free to ask him anything. He can even help set up your account.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="onboarding-card-actions">
      <a class="button back-button back" href="#onboardingCard4">Back</a>
      <a class="button next-button complete" href="#onboardingCard6">This is amazing, let's get started!</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
<!--
  <div class="onboarding-intro">
   <div class="onboarding-intro-stages">
    <div class="onboarding-intro-stage stage1 content">
     <p><i class="icon-hand-wave animation-set"></i> Welcome to Plutio, {{ customer.first_name }}.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="onboarding-intro-stage stage2 content">
     <p>We're setting up your account, it won't take a minute...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="onboarding-intro-stage stage3 content">
     <p>In the meantime, here's a quick introduction into Plutio...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fireworks">
     <div class="before"></div>
     <div class="after"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
-->
 </div>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] instead.

Comment: Sorry, I will do one now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `href` in the first link.

> ```
> <a class="button next-button next">Nice, what's next?</a>
> ```

Comment: -.- this fixed it. 

Now it shows the other divs when clicking next, any idea how I can show only the active div?

Comment: Set `display: none` on the ones which aren't active

Comment: But the first div isn't showing now. To show it I have to do first-of-type: display block, but that would keep it shown